# How to Enqueue a list of items in C#?

Tags: c#, collections, queue

Using lists I use

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.AddRange(otherList);
```

How to do this using a Queue?, this Collection does not have a AddRange Method.

```
Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();
q.AddRange(otherList); //does not exists
```

Comment: Is the answer basically "You can at construction, but there is no optimized AddRange equivalent other than calling Enqueue one-by-one." ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Queue` has a constructor that takes in an `ICollection`. You can pass your list into the queue to initialize it with the same elements:

```
var queue = new Queue<T>(list);
```

in your case use as follows

```
Queue<int> ques = new Queue<int>(otherList);
```

Comment: Solves the OP's question, but only works for an empty Queue.

Answer (score 44):

```
otherList.ForEach(o => q.Enqueue(o));
```

You can also use this extension method:

```
    public static void AddRange<T>(this Queue<T> queue, IEnumerable<T> enu) {
        foreach (T obj in enu)
            queue.Enqueue(obj);
    }

    Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();
    q.AddRange(otherList); //Work!
```

Comment: you can use `otherList.Foreach(q.Enqueue)` without boxing it into another lambda expression

Answer (score 6):

You can initialize the queue list:

```
Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>(otherList);
```